# EditText with numeric keyboard but allowing alphanumeric values

Tags: java, android, xml, keyboard, android-edittext

Problem:

- my own class which extends EditTextPreference
- a method within that class called "`setInputType()`"
  with `this.getEditText().setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);`
- my xml with elements of my own EditText-class with

  - title, summary, key, defaultValue, digits, nothing else.
  - `android:digits="1234567890"`

What i want is:

- the default value will always be numeric, but leading zeros have to be possible.
  so my thought was, that I have to either have a inputtype "phone" or "text", although i dont want letters to be allowed. as you see

my problem:

I can type the numbers from `0123456789`, but my edittext opens with the normal keyboard.
but when I tried to change it to numeric keyboard, I couldnt manage to make the 0 be allowed.
Is there a clean solution? everything i found is either just making the numeric keyboard as default OR allowing my wanted digits.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change XML's Edit text with simply this ::

```
<EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:singleLine="true"
    />
```

And code as ::

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

Comment: unfortunately this didnt change anything. i still dont get a numeric keyboard :/